# How to invoke APIs from Java using https client with ssl certificate

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, java-http-client

I am invoking rest API  from Java file using  HttpClient. By using that I am able to call http API but not https API.

I am getting below error, while calling httpsapi.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
```

I want to call https API using `CloseableHttpClient`.

I am having certificate file that is having private key.
Please let me know how I can use this private key to call API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call API using `https` you need to configure `SSLContext` and set it to your `HttpClient`. Refer below sample code. This is just the sample, you can load keystore and truststore in different way like from classpath, form file system etc.., make the changes accordingly.

```
    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

    KeyStore identity = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);
    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyManagerFactory.init(identity, "password".toCharArray());
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.3");
    sslContext.init(
        keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), 
        trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), 
        null
    );
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLContext(sslContext)
            .setSSLHostnameVerifier(new DefaultHostnameVerifier())
            .build();
```